# Javascript global variables set modified within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I've got a a couple of functions similar to the following that will return an error should one occur:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    call();
});
function call() {
    getBounceRate();
    getVisitsToday();
    getMom();
}
function getVisitsToday() {
    $('#loader-visits').show();
    $('#visits-today').closest('#show').hide();
    $('#visits-today').next().remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'framework/AJAX/stats_data.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'type=visitsToday',
        success: function(data) {
            if (!$.isNumeric(data)) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#visits-today').parent().show().html(data.error);
                $('#loader-visits').hide();
               // trigger error so refresh doesn't happen

            } else {
                $('#visits-today').html(data);
                $('#visits-today').after('<span class="text-muted">unique visitors</span>');
                $('#loader-visits').hide();
                $('#visits-today').closest('#show').fadeIn();
            }
        },
    });
}
```

else where in the code at the end of the script I set a refresh interval: `var refInterval = window.setInterval('call()', 10000);`

I want to be able to stop the refresh interval should an error occur. I've tried doing it by defining sort of a global variable `window.hasErrors = false` and setting it to true in the if else statement of the function and then seeing if it is false when the set interval is called but that didn't work.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Comment: so clear the interval

Answer (score 1):

`var ii = window.setInterval('call()', 10000);`

Some error handler

```
function errorHandler(){
   window.clearInterval(ii);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval